# Software that monitors network bandwidth usage per process 1

Tags: windows, networking, monitoring

I am looking for a software that can monitor and inform me the Network bandwidth usage per process.

For example, I have my streaming server .exe running on a given port. I want to monitor that process and get a notification via email if the connection is dropped or is less than 256kbps for example.

Any software that does this?

Mainly the ones I found on the internet like SterJo NetStalker or Net Monitor provide real time monitoring and most of them do not show the current speed on a specific port.

Answer (score 1):

NetBalancer will be the suitable application for you. https://netbalancer.com/

I am using it for years. You can monitor the network bandwidth usage per process with this application.

Answer (score 0):

The python library [psutil](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil) provides the necessary information via [psutil.net_connections](https://pythonhosted.org/psutil/#psutil.net_connections) so you should be able to knock up a background script to monitor such usage and log or send alerts, (keeping in mind that if the usage drops because the network is lost/disconnected the alerts aren't going anywhere so you might need to have such a process provide usage statistics to a monitor elsewhere that sends alerts if it doesn't receive them.

For a ready built program that makes use of this to do more or less what you are asking, and a lot more, see [GRR Rapid Response](https://github.com/google/grr).